# In detail: mklink and its options

Tags: batch-file, directory, cmd

I recently followed a small tutorial on howto install apache on a systems where you're not the admin. Basically, the original htdocs and conf folders were copied to a map I have ownership over, the original ones deleted and then symbolic links were created.

Now, I checked `mklink /?` and it gives several options.

1. Directory symbolic link
2. Hard Link
3. Directory junction

[Microsoft technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) doesn't offer much explanation as to what the last 2 options really do.

So I'm wondering if there's someone here who can tell me what these options do and perhaps give an example of a situation where this is really usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on MSDN on [Hardlinks and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006(VS.85).aspx).  It says:

> A hard link is the file system
>   representation of a file by which more
>   than one path references a single file
>   in the same volume.

And:

> A junction (also called a soft link)
>   differs from a hard link in that the
>   storage objects it references are
>   separate directories, and a junction
>   can link directories located on
>   different local volumes on the same
>   computer. Otherwise, junctions operate
>   identically to hard links.

Comment: Not entirely identical, though. When doing directory tree traversal you may choose to omit junction points where the difference will be apparent.